# Error in groovy script

Tags: json, groovy

show this msg for me

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.write() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [62, UTF-8] Possible solutions: write(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), write(java.lang.String), wait(), size(), canWrite(), wait(long)

and code is

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
requestTestStepName = "Criar/Login Usuario 1"  

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(requestTestStepName).getPropertyValue("response")
response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
userId = response.userId

new File( "C:/tc/json/userId_H24_userid.txt" ).write(userId, "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is staring at you from the really helpful error message..

You need to wrap your `62` userid up as a String:

```
new File( "C:/tc/json/userId_H24_userid.txt" ).write("$userId", "UTF-8")
```